# Range of numbers to array of number strings?

Tags: ruby

I currently want to get the numbers from 1 to 23 as a string.

The method I arrived at feels slightly hard to read:

```
CHROMOSOME_NUMBERS = (1..23).to_a.map { |n| n.to_s }
```

Is there a prettier way of doing it?

Comment: 23 numbers isn't that much, you could use Ruby's `%w` literal: `%w[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23]`

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about improving working code. That makes it on-topic for [codereview.se] and off-topic for [so].

Comment: @theTinMan: As said, it's on-topic here because it asks *how* to improve rather than *what*. It's off-topic on Code Review.

Comment: Regardless of the technicalities, I've never seen a question as trivial as this one on Code Review.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
('1'..'23').to_a
=> ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23"]
```

Comment: Something like this is what I was hoping for.

Comment: Instead of tossing out code, explain why this works.

Comment: @theTinMan, there is nothing to explain. This is a standard Ruby implementation. It can create a range of strings as well.

Answer (score 8):

There is `map` method defined for `Range` (because `Range` includes `Enumerable` module), so you don't have to convert it manually to array:

```
CHROMOSOME_NUMBERS = (1..23).map(&:to_s)
```

Comment: Derf. I tried `CHROMOSOME_NUMBERS = (1..23).map(&to_s)` myself.